# Removing a blank character in-front of a value in a cell C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

I'm currently busy with a application that manipulates excel data using C#. I have encountered a problem however.

The data in the column all has a blank space in-front of it, which messes up with the Sum() functionality.

I've got this method to read each row from the column and remove the blank space in-front of the data.

```
private void BlankCheck()
        {
            string Val,NT;
            int RCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            for(int X = 3; X < RCount; X++)
            {
                Val = (string)(xlWorksheet.Cells[X, 8] as Excel.Range).Text;
                NT = Val.Trim();
                xlWorksheet.Cells[X, 8] = "\b"+NT.ToString();
            }
            xlApp.Quit();
            ReleaseObject(xlWorksheet);
            ReleaseObject(xlWorkbook);
            ReleaseObject(xlApp);
        }
```

The results produced by this are correct as shown by the screenshot below
[image: Results of the method]

Now this is where the problem is, when opening up the new excel document, the blank spaces are all still in-front of the data. So I've added the "\b" to the string when it writes to the cell, however this is the result.

[image: Excel sheet result]

I'm not sure why those [] have appeared ? 
Any suggestions ?

[image: Edited Data]

This is what the excel column looks like both before and after the code has run without the /b. Not sure if you can see it, but there is a blank character in-front of the times. Here is the code too for those who have asked.

```
private void BlankCheck()
        {
            string Val,NT;
            int RCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            for(int X = 3; X < RCount; X++)
            {
                Val = (string)(xlWorksheet.Cells[X, 8] as Excel.Range).Text;
                NT = Val.Trim();
                xlWorksheet.Cells[X, 8] = NT.ToString();
            }
            xlApp.Quit();
            ReleaseObject(xlWorksheet);
            ReleaseObject(xlWorkbook);
            ReleaseObject(xlApp);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should not need to add "\b" - can you show us the code and the output when you do not use "\b" please

Comment: Why are you adding '\b' to the cell value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would help, if you called xlWorkbook.Save() before releasing the object.